# app crashing after trying to load an skspritenode twice?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I asked a question before and i wound up deleting it as i though i figured it out, but i actually just narrowed it down.

When one of my nodes hits into an obstacle, the game presents a score label and a restart button.  But if my node hits a different object after the initial hit, the app crashes. If i run the game with // in front of the the label and restart to take them out of the equation the game runs fine, but if i run the game with them, it crashes.

This leads me to believe its crashing because its trying to load the restart button and score label twice.  I might be totally wrong but how can i correct this?

Comment: With what error app crashes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably right.

Trying to `addchild` is how I presume you're adding things to the scene. If you try to add something to a scene or object that's already added to a something, you get a crash.

So you're probably trying to add your restart and score label to something, as a child, when they already have a parent, and this is causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT!

I added if statements to make the app only run my collision code after 1 collision and not 2

```
var collision = Int()


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

        if collision == 0{
        if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.bird) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.obstacle)) {

            collisionWithObstacle(bird: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        }
        }
        else if collision != 0{
            if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.bird) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCatagory.obstacle)) {

        }
        }
    }


   func collisionWithObstacle(bird:SKSpriteNode){


        collision = collision+1
        scoreTimer.invalidate()
        obstacleTimer.invalidate()
        addChild(restart)
        scoreLabel2.text = "Score: \(score1)"
        addChild(scoreLabel2)

    }
```

hope this can help someone else because although it seems trivial in hindsight, it was a head scratcher for a few nights after work.